# how to detect if the order of two lists changed and if changed then show newly added or deleted members in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I want to compare two lists which has properties Id,Number,Name so i want to compare both list
for example
if NewList has

```
Id Name   Number
1  Test    1
2  Test2   2
```

and Oldlist has

```
Id  NewList Number
1    Test    1
```

so when we compare both list i should show text that in NewList Test2 is added
or if i removed from new list then should show text that Element is removed on newline

here is my code which i have tried

```
StringBuilder oldPref = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder newPref = new StringBuilder();
newList = GetPref(NewInfo).OrderBy(p => p.Number).Where(x => x.Number> 0).ToList();
OldList = GetPref(OldInfo).OrderBy(p => p.Number).Where(x => x.Number> 0).ToList();
   
foreach (var item in OldList)
{
  oldPref .Append(item.Name + Environment.NewLine);
}
foreach (var item in newList)
{
  newPref .Append(item.Name + Environment.NewLine);
}

if (!String.Equals(oldPref , newPref ))
{
  note.Append("Order Changed " + Environment.NewLine);
}
note.Append("From " + Environment.NewLine);
note.Append(oldPref);
note.Append("To " + Environment.NewLine);
note.Append(newPref);
```

can anybody help me with this how i do it properly thanks in advance

Comment: Is _Id_ an unique key that identifies each element in the two lists?

Comment: no the list of hardcoded values so it is like this as oldlist i am fetching the list for that record from db and getting the new list from ui then seralizing both list so both list may have same value if old and new list has elements with same number and if i change from ui it must be different so then i want to show new element is added or if i remove ui a element is deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to iterate through both lists, one at a time, and see if the other list contains each element of the list that is being iterated:

```
    List<MyClass> oldList = ...;
    List<MyClass> newList = ...;
    
    foreach(MyClass item in oldList){
        if(newList.Contains(item) == false) {
            (insert logic for when item has been removed from oldList)
        }
    }
    
    foreach(MyClass item in newList){
        if(oldList.Contains(item) == false) {
            (insert logic for when item has been added to oldList)
        }
    }
```